# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch while using http://localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, api, google-chrome, localhost, google-calendar-api

I am getting the Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch error while trying to use just a simple NPM start loading my react web application in http://localhost:3000/. I am very confused on what to put in the OAuth 2.0 section for Authorized Redirect URI and Authorized Javascript Origins, not sure if having those correctly entered would even solve the problem. I believe I have all the code entered correctly with my API key. All I am trying to do is create a task list application that allows you to add a task with the push of a button, into my google calendar. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Form from './Components/Form';
import TaskList from './Components/TaskList';

function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('all');
  const [filteredTasks, setFilteredTasks] = useState([]);

  // Google Calendar API
  var gapi = window.gapi
  var CLIENT_ID = ""; // Hidden for privacy
  var API_KEY = ""; // Hidden for privacy
  var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];
  var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";
  //
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getLocalTasks()
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const filterHandler = () => {
      switch(status) {
        case 'completed':
          setFilteredTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.completed === true));
          break;
        case 'uncompleted':
          setFilteredTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.completed === false));
          break;
          
        default:
          setFilteredTasks(tasks);
          break;
      }
    };

    filterHandler();
    saveLocalTasks();
  }, [tasks, status]);


  const handleClick = () => {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
      console.log('Loaded Client')

      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES,
      })

      gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => console.log('Boom!'))

      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
      .then(() => {
        
        var event = {
          'summary': 'Awesome Event!',
          'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
          'description': 'Really great refreshments',
          'start': {
            'dateTime': '2020-06-28T09:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
          },
          'end': {
            'dateTime': '2020-06-28T17:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
          },
          'recurrence': [
            'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
          ],
          'attendees': [
            {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
            {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'}
          ],
          'reminders': {
            'useDefault': false,
            'overrides': [
              {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
              {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
            ]
          }
        }

        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'resource': event,
        })

        request.execute(event => {
          console.log(event)
          window.open(event.htmlLink)
        })

      })
    })
  }


  // Save to LocalStorage
  const saveLocalTasks = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
  };

  const getLocalTasks = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
      localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify([]));
    } else {
      let taskLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
      setTasks(taskLocal);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>My Task List</header>

      {/* State */}
      <Form 
      inputText={inputText} 
      tasks={tasks} 
      setTasks={setTasks} 
      setInputText={setInputText}
      setStatus={setStatus}
      />

      <TaskList
      filteredTasks={filteredTasks} 
      setTasks={setTasks}
      tasks={tasks}
      />

      <button onClick={handleClick} className="addEvent">Add Event</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have also tried looking up previous questions about the same issue and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: This is in regards to using the google calendar API.

Comment: You need OAuth2 for the requests you want to make. Google will issue different type of credentials depending on the type of application. For web applications, they want you to whitelist the Javascript origins for your authorization request, as well as the redirect URI where your client will be redirected to after successful authorization. Both of these addresses you need to specify in the consent screen of the project, and then download the credentials object again. Let meknow if this helped.

Comment: Yes that does make sense, but what do you mean by whitelist my JS Origins? I know where you are talking about, but in the JS origin and Redirect URI, would I just put "localhost:3000" ?

Comment: Do I add the downloaded 0Auth 2.0 file code to my package.json file in my code?

Comment: You can read more about it here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingcred

Comment: Do you know which line of code the issue is coming from?